# How to use absolute paths with TinyXML2

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

I am using TinyXML2 to load/edit/save xml settings.

I have found this works: (success == `true`)

```
tinyxml2::XMLDocument *printjobxml;
printjobxml = new tinyxml2::XMLDocument();
success = printjobxml->LoadFile("myxml.xml");
```

...and this doesn't: (success always == `false`)

```
tinyxml2::XMLDocument *printjobxml;
printjobxml = new tinyxml2::XMLDocument();
success = printjobxml->LoadFile("C:\\myxml.xml");
```

The only difference being the absolute path instead of relative.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XMLDocument::LoadFile()` return XML_NO_ERROR (0) on success, so the second example is works fine, but the first is not. I bet the first `LoadFile()` call returns XML_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (3).

Comment: That solved it - thank you! This is a difference from TinyXML 1 which meant the old examples confused me. Thanks :)